# Check if the day is between two given days using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel-2013

I've limited knowledge in coding with VBA in Excel and have run into a problem. I'm trying to write a code where it does something based on what day of the week it is.

I'm extracting the day of the week as string and then using a IF...ELSE bit. Code is attached below:

```vb
Sub Schedule()

    Dim Today As String

    Today = Format(Date, "dddd")

    If Today >= "Monday" And Today <= "Thursday" Then
 
    'code to do something

    ElseIf Today = "Friday" Then

    'code to do something

    ElseIf Today >= "Saturday" And Today <= "Sunday" Then

    'code to do something

    End If

End Sub
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Use `Today = Format(Date, "w")` that way you will get 1-7 (Day of week, starting with Sunday = 1) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Select Case ...` is fine for this - and do use constants, not magic numbers:

```vb
Sub Schedule()

    Select Case Weekday(Date)
        Case vbMonday To vbThursday
            ' Code to do something.
        Case vbFriday
            ' Code to do something else.
        Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
            ' Code to do some fun.
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `WeekDay()` to extract an integer representing the current day of the week:

```
Dim Today As VbDayOfWeek

Today = Weekday(Date)

If Today >= vbMonday And Today <= vbThursday Then
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply comparison operands (`>` or `<`) to strings so you will need to use the `.WeekDay()` function instead of formatting to string.

Here is the documentation: [WeekDay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekday-function) please note the second optional parameter.

Here is the code:

```vb
Dim Today as Long

Today = WeekDay(Date)

If Today >= 2 And Today <= 5 Then
    'do something
ElseIf Today = 6 Then
    'do something
ElseIf Today = 7 Or Today = 1 Then
    'do something
End If
```